# 10/3 down to 12/2 for Air Conditioner?

Tags: electrical

Recently started digging around further in my new basement. Found the air conditioner is wired as follows:::
10/3 wire coming from panel that is connected to a double 15A breaker (red to 1, black to the other, white is simply not connected, ground to ground block). - in a j-box 15’ down the ceiling the 10/3 connects to a 12/2 (black-black red-white ground-ground). From the j-box the 12/2 runs outside to the air conditioner another 20’ down the wall. 
Don’t know when this was installed. Based on the wire dating it can’t be pre-2005. I didn’t wire this but want to fix it if this is not correct. House hasn’t burned down yet, obviously, but this just seems odd. 
My thought is pull the 10/3 out of the equation and change it all to 12/2. What does the breaker need to be? Thank you!
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Wire size is not a problem.. Type of 12/2 cable, size of or presence of raceway outdoors, marking of the white used as an ungrounded conductor may be issues. Breaker size is determined from nameplate of AC unit.

Comment: This must be a small air conditoner - it's running off a 15A breaker?  You might double check the power requirements of the AC and make sure you're looking at the right breaker.

Comment: @JPhi1618 -- a 1.5 ton or perhaps even a 2 ton outdoor unit will run happily on a 15A breaker from the numbers I've seen

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate on your air conditioner's outdoor unit and of your panel (including the label on the inside of the front cover) please?

Answer (score 2):

### You're always allowed to upsize wire

I don't know how your house came to have legacy air conditioning wiring that large, *yes I do. Air conditioners have gotten more efficient and past owners may have retrofitted insulation*.

But regardless, if the requirement is for 14 AWG wire, you are *always* allowed to use the larger #12 or still larger #10.

There is also nothing wrong with an unused white wire "coming along for the ride".

However, when a white wire is used as a hot in a 240V cable, you are required to mark the white wire with tape.  I strongly prefer wrapping the tape around the wire; flags can easily be torn off, especially as they age.

As far as breakers, if your panel is Eaton, Cutler-Hammer, BRyant, Challenger, or Westinghouse, Eaton breakers are almost certainly correct. If it's anything else, it's probably a hazardous mismatch, but *anything is possible* with Eaton; we'd need the panel brand and model, and the lettering on the breaker to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Start with knowing the amp draw* on the nameplate of the AC unit. If it is 15A or less, then the 15A breaker and 12ga wire is fine. But the 10ga wire may have been used to factor in the "voltage drop" over distance and you should not mess with it.

Or it might have been originally installed for a larger AC unit, then when a smaller one replaced it, they just used the existing wire. Absolutely nothing wrong with that, so long as everyone knows that the maximum continuous load is going to be limited to 16A by the 12ga wire in the circuit, and that's where it can get tricky for the "future guy". Most people are lazy and will look at one end of a circuit only. So if they look at the origin and see 10ga wire hooked to a 15A breaker, they might "ASS-u-me" that they can replace the breaker with a 30A, since 10ga wire is rated for that. But the 12ga splice down the line then becomes a fire hazard. Likewise if they look at the 12ga end and see a black and a white wire, they might ASS-u-me that it is a 120V circuit with a hot and a neutral (white is always supposed to be neutral) and burn up some 120V device. So in either case the way it was done is not considered "best practice" even though it might not technically be illegal. At the very least if you do nothing else, I suggest getting some red heat scrink or electrical tape to put on those white wires in order to denote to "future guy" that something is not as it might seem.

- In many HVAC equipment connection systems, they don't actually show you the FLA (Full Load Amps) of the unit, they provide you with another value called the MCA (Minimum Circuit Ampacity) and/or MOCP (Maximum Over Current Protection). If they give you one or both of those values, then the "125%" factor on the circuit requirements is ALREADY in those numbers, you don't do it again. So for example if they tell you that it has an MCA of 17A, then because #12 is rated for 20A, you are fine. In that case if they then went on to give you an MOCP of 30A, the 15A breaker would still be "legal", but might nuisance trip. If it hasn't, then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the great insight. Went and checked and written on the compressor states the “max fuse amps or max circuit breaker” is 15. So the double Eaton 15A is correct. Now to just tuck it correctly through the floor joists since it’s all stapled across the bottom of them...

Comment: Hold on @Uwtriguy, whether the Eaton breaker is correct depends on the type of panel you have *and* the type of breaker.   For instance if your panel is Square D HOMeline, the only correct Eaton breaker is the rare CL, a common BR would be wrong.

Comment: Eaton Cutler-Hammer 125A panel.  Breaker is a double 15 Eaton BR215. Type C215. ——everything in the panel is an Eaton BR except a 15A GE that’s off and actually has nothing running to it. Looks like that’s going to get replaced with a BR115 regardless of it being brought into service or not.